# ADo dot net passing the table datatype as parameter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

what are the changes I need to for my DAL to support this. Kindly Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to pass `TypeName`, like:

```
var par = adoCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameterName", dataTable);
par.TypeName = "dbo.ParameterType";
```

Comment: I need to write generic override for the Ado.net method's to support  this structure datatype i.e i need to write an override for the Execute Scalar to accept this data type.